# ffmpeg: need for speed

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, flv, mp4, webm

I am using ffmpeg to convert a set of images (bmps) with an audio track into Web ready video. Target formats are h.264 mp4, webm and flv. 
This is on a Windows Azure extra-large instance (8 proc) using the prebuilt zeranoe static builds ( http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Suppose I'm willing to sacrifice quality and size for raw speed. What options for each format will yield the quickest result?

My "baseline" command looks like this (swap the extension for the other formats):

```
ffmpeg -y -i frames%5d.bmp -i audio.mp3 -r 23.97 out.mp4
```

I can change the inputs to other formats if needed (jpg images, aac audio, etc).

Comment: This is more general FFMPEG question, than Azure question. One hint though, use the 32bit ffmpeg executable. I was having issues with the 64bit one and found out that the 32bit works perfactly and stable.

Comment: Have you looked at the Media Services? THese won't give you raw throughput on a single request, but will allow some fairly large scaleout of jobs.

Comment: @bdcm I'm building a custom video per user. I need individual requests to be hella fast

Comment: @astaykov I see no perf difference between 64 and 32 bit, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @roufamatic I had no perf, but stability/codecs issues using the 64bit version, random errors, unrecognized codecs, once convert clearly, once fail, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major "knob" you change the quality/encoding speed balance for any format is the [bitrate](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Codec-AVOptions).  In testing just now, a video that takes 97 seconds to encode with default settings, bitrate ~900k, took less than half that with the bitrate dialed down to 100k.  The output video was much smaller, and the quality was noticeably worse.

In your case, coming from images, you can probably get a major speedup from turning off motion estimation as mentioned in [FFmpeg's encoding tips](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Tips):

> If your computer is not fast enough, you can speed up the compression at the expense of the compression ratio. You can use ’-me zero’ to speed up motion estimation, and ’-g 0’ to disable motion estimation completely (you have only I-frames, which means it is about as good as JPEG compression). [Note that more recent versions of FFmpeg use `-me_method` in place of `-me`.]

In testing, the 97-second encode finished in *20* seconds with `-g 0`.  There was much less compression, 63% the original size versus 25% with default settings, but the quality remains good unlike low-bitrate encodings.

Here are the complete results from my quick testing, time is real time used for encoding:
Baseline, 27M MOV to mp4, bitrate ~900k: 97s
with `-me_method zero`: 84s
with [`-flags2 fast`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Codec-AVOptions): 84s
with `-b 500k`: 75s
with `-b 100k`: 43s
with `-g 0`: 20s

with `-flags2 fast` and `-b 100k` and `-g 0`: 12s (the output looks *terrible*)

There might be other format-specific tweaks, but I wouldn't expect significant speedups from those compared to the methods listed above..

Answer (score 1):

What is the resolution of these images? Using as low as a resolution as possible will give you better performance. Also use the -threads option in ffmpeg to use the 8 cores optimally.

Comment: I can't control the resolution (760x442). Ffmpeg adds in -threads 0 by default, causing it to use 12 threads on an 8 proc box. I actually saved a second of rendering time by using -threads 8. It's a start!